# Need help using mod_sendfile on openshift

Tags: apache, python-2.7, openshift

Does anyone know if there is a way to use mod_sendfile with OpenShift hosting.  I am using a python 2.7 cartridge, and it does not seem like I have any control over the apache modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can not install apache modules on the python gear, you basically have two options:
1.)  Create your own apache cartridge for use on openshift online that includes the modules that you want to use.
2.)  Add installing mod_sendfile to http://openshift.com/ideas and get users to vote on it.